# Ionic - Capacitor - Android Flavours - cant run app in a emulator or real device

Tags: android, capacitor, ionic5, android-flavors

I have a Ionic Capacitor project working since Jun 2021.
A couple of week ago I implemented flavours in android to build 2 aplications with the same source code like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
// Specifies one flavor dimension.
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
  develop {
    dimension "version"
  }
  demo {
    dimension "version"
    applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
    versionNameSuffix "-demo"
  }
}
```

If i build the project from Android Studio, everything works fine.
Android Studio builds 4 apks (develop-debug, develop-prod, demo-debug and demo-prod)

[image]

But, since I made this implementation, I can't run the app from Visual Studio Code using the "npx cap run android" command.
It's giving me this error:

```
✖ Deploying app-debug.apk to Pixel_4a_API_30 - failed!
[error] Selected emulator emulator-5554
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Volumes/Macintosh HD -
        Data/Development/ionic_workspace/wallet/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
```

It looks like is not finding the apk because after applying flavours the apks are not in "outputs/apk/debug/"
I can't found anything on internet about this. I'm thinking that I need to change something on the Ionic project to tell where find the APKs, but I don't know.

Any idea of what can I do?

Thanks frot the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the flavor you want to run in the capacitor config file.

```
{
  ...(existing fields)
  "android": {
    "flavor": "develop"
  }
}
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Or directly with the run command using the `--flavor` parameter

`npx cap run android --flavor develop`

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/commands/run